# ASP.NET MVC. Pdf generation. Put image to PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have PDF file and i need dynamically put image(logo) in some place of this pdf file.

I just need to say "here is image put it to special position on pdf or something and give me output". And than i pass this output in my controller in response. That's it.

Could anybody suggest any good free library for such case.

iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) Seems to let you do that and [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1364-add-image-to-pdf-document-using-itextsharp.aspx) show you how.